# Can't seem to understand this javascript code! if(!this.class)

Tags: javascript

New to javascript here.

So I've been trying to learn to use Raphael.js and came across this http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/AeU2r/ snippet of code.

Now if you look at line 167, there is this "if" statement I just don't understand.

```
   Raphael.el.style = function (state, style, aniOptions)
    {
     if (!this.class)
     {
        this.class = style ? style : 'default';
        this.aniOptions = aniOptions ? aniOptions : null;

        // start assigning some basic behaviors
        this.mouseover(function () { this.style('hover'); });
    ....
```

What class? What is it returning? Who is returning it?

What is it even checking? That it's a class?

Comment: Right above the `if` statement, type in `console.log(this);` and activate your browsers console. Then re-run the jsFiddle to view the Objects.

Comment: Note that `class` is [a reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in JavaScript, so that code looks a bit dodgy. I would not use `class` as a property name in JavaScript to avoid confusion in future ECMAScript versions.

Comment: It just checks whether the `class` property of `this` has a (falsy) value. If you are unfamiliar with objects, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Raphael documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.el), `Raphael.el` is a way of adding one's own methods to the `Raphael.element` class. In general, the purpose of this class is to make it easier to manipulate SVG elements.

`this.class` in the code example has nothing to do with the the word class in the programming sense, as used in the preceding sentences. Nor (as far as I can see) is it part of the standard Raphael framework. Nor does it refer to the `class` attribute that HTML and SVG elements can have, and which is usually accessed in javascript using `element.className` or `element.setAttribute('class', '...')`.

`this` refers to the element wrapper object (an instance of `Raphael.element`), and it seems that the person who wrote this method has simply used the name `class` to store some additional information in the element wrapper. (As pointed out in comments, this might be a bad idea because `class` is a reserved keyword in javascript; but anyway, it works.)

Specifically, in the example, `this.class` is initially `undefined` because it has not been assigned a value anywhere else in Raphael or in the code. In the `if` clause, `!undefined` evaluates to `true`, and in the following line, no value has been passed to the function for `style`, so that `style ? style : 'default'` evaluates to 'default'. So `this.class` is assigned the value 'default'. Afterwards, if you right-click on a shape and choose *Use custom style*, the `class` for that shape becomes 'custom'.

Note that javascript very easily lets you refer to, and assign values to, properties of an object that have not been initialised anywhere. It does not throw an error but simply returns `undefined` if no value has been assigned.

You can see all this by inserting a line that logs what's going on to the browser console:

```
console.log('style', state, style, aniOptions, this, 'class:', this.class);
```

and then using your browser's developer tools to see the output ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AeU2r/42/)).

Comment: @hellokc Glad it helped... feel free to accept this as the answer, unless you're holding out for more answers.

Answer (score 0):

It checks if a property `class` is defined and if not, it will assign it to `style ? style : 'default'`.

Comment: "You could also write it as" --- well, it's not an 100% equivalent to `if (!this.class)`. I would remove that from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is simply a conditional statement, look at it as an abbreviated if-else-clause which checks if `style` evaluates to true or false, if it's true `this.Class` will have the value of `style`, if it's not it will get the value of `'default'`.

I don't know how raphael.js works, but it looks to me like it is simply a html element class.

Comment: *Checks yet again if this.class evaluates to false* ... uhm, no? It checks whether `style` is falsy or truthy. It *assigns* the result to `this.class`. So overall it does: *"If `this.class` does not have a value, assign `style` to it if it has a value, otherwise `'default'` and do a bunch of other things."*

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for pointing the `very bad` part of my answer.